# Access textarea from code behind class

Tags: asp.net, text, webforms, textarea, code-behind

I have a text area in a webform page. I want to display some records in the text area which will be retrieved from the db. I would like to know how to access the text area from my code behind class.

I am using normal webforms not master pages.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use a asp:TextBox and set its MultiLine property to 'true' it will render as a textarea in html and then you can get and set the text of the control as with a normal asp:TextBox.